# Activate the 2nd tab of the tab panel

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a `tabpanel`, and a button on the 1st tab. When i `click` on that `button`, i need to `setfocus` to the 2nd tab and `activate` it (as in show content that belongs to that tab). My code is as follows, and i unable to `setFocus` or `activate` that tab from the `Button click event`.

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyTabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    activeTab: 0,

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Tab 1',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'MyButton',
                    listeners: {
                        click: {
                            fn: me.onButtonClick,
                            scope: me
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Tab 2'
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Tab 3'
            }]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onButtonClick: function (button, e, options) {
        // Set Focus, and activate the 2nd tab
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-setActiveTab

There are also several examples of setting the active tab at the class level documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Find the container of the tab panel. to get the container you can use Ext.getCmp

```
Ext.getCmp('center-region').setActiveTab('your-tab-name');
```